# Changing directory in markdown: setwd does not work on markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I have a r-Markdown file with the following heading:

```
---
title: "my paper"
author: "name"
date: \today
header-includes:
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    fig_caption: yes
  word_document:
    toc: yes
latex_engine: xelatex
indent: yes
bibliography: library.bib
references: 
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
hyperfootnotes: yes
---
```

I would like to import some data that is stored in another directory? how can I do it?

I am using `setwd()` but it does not appear to work

````
```{r, include=FALSE }
# import the data
rm(list=ls())
library(haven)
setwd("/Users/folderwithdata")
data<-read_dta("mydata.dta")
````

This return an error `Error: 'mydata.dta' does not exist in current working directory`

however, if I put the data in the folder of the markdown, it is able to upload it.
DOes anyone know what I am doing wrong? is there a way to change the working directory to upload data in markdown?

Comment: This is by design. And `setwd()` really *should not be used* — it’s unnecessary, and causes all sorts of issues. Same goes for `rm(list = ls())`. See https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/. — Instead of using `setwd()`, you’d specify the entire, relevant part of the path when accessing files (in this case, via `read_dta`). But more generally you should virtually never use absolute paths inside your code either, since they make the code unportable.

Comment: Is there any way I can use here to change the wd? I don't fully get as `here works`. I generally organize folders with a project folder that is subdivided in output, data and code folders. The markdown is in the output folder, while the .dta file is in the data folder. Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Yes, with the project outline as you’ve described you’d specify the path as `data/…`. I.e. in your code: `data <- read_dta("data/mydata.dta")`. I urge you to read the link I posted above, it explains this in more detail (but note that you in general *do not* need to use the ‘here’ package, and I recommend against its usage, since it attempts to fix the symptoms rather than the cause of the issues).